# How correctly use Include in EF Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

i have models

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BrandId")]
    public virtual BrandModel Brand { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class BrandModel
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
   
    public ProductModel Product { get; set; }
}
```

my context

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<BrandModel> Brand { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductModel> Product { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BrandModel>().ToTable("Brand").HasKey(k=>k.BrandId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BrandModel>().Property(p => p.BrandId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(30);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductModel>().ToTable("Product").HasKey(k => k.ProductId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductModel>()
            .HasOne<BrandModel>(p => p.Brand)
            .WithOne(b => b.Product)
            .HasForeignKey<ProductModel>(pr => pr.BrandId);
    }
}
```

i want take products with Brand. 1 product have 1 brand
then i make simple method with include

```
var result = await _context.Product.Include(x => x.Brand).ToListAsync();
```

i see data from the database, but there is a loop

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.
```

it finds a product with a brand, but the brand has a product model that has a brand model ...

how can you remove this loop and get a product with a brand?

Comment: Does [this](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/59199593/-net-core-3-0-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported) answer your question?

Comment: Also if you don't want to switch to Json.Net - .NET 5 has now support for [reference loop handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.referencehandler.preserve?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by object nesting or preloading of ef query (associated loading), just like the "object loop" explained, the hierarchy is too deep to parse.

Add nuget package

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

Add the configuration in startup

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(option =>
            //Ignore circular references
            option.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
```